# Child Row always expanded in datatables.net

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, datatables

i have created parent child row table using datatables.net. On Click of a row the child row is shown. but i want child always open with out any click event on row. Can somebody suggest me how to achieve it

here is my code

```
 var ecumTbl= S$("#EncumbranceSummaryTable").DataTable(
        {                        
            "footerCallback": function ( row, data, start, end, display ) {                  
                var api = this.api(), data;

                // Remove the formatting to get integer data for summation
                var intVal = function ( i ) {
                    return typeof i === 'string' ?
                        i.replace(/[\$,]/g, '')*1 :
                        typeof i === 'number' ?
                        i : 0;
                };
                // Total over all pages
                if(api.column(3).data().length)
                {
                    total = api
                    .column( 1 )
                    .data()
                    .reduce( function (a, b) {
                        return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                    } );
                }
                else
                {
                    total =0
                };


                // Total over this page
                if(api.column(3).data().length)
                {
                    pageTotal = api
                        .column( 3, { page: 'current'} )
                        .data()
                        .reduce( function (a, b) {
                            return intVal(a) + intVal(b);
                        }, 0 );

                    // Update footer
                    $( api.column(2).footer() ).html(
                        'Contract Total'
                    );
                    $( api.column(3).footer() ).html(
                       formatCurrency(pageTotal)
                  );

                }
                else{
                    pageTotal=0;
                };
            },

                        "aoColumns": [

                                    {
                                        "sTitle": "", "sWidth": "10%"
                                    },
                                                { "sTitle": "Sub total for PO #", "mData": "PO_Num", "sWidth": "15%" },
                                                { "sTitle": "Encumbrance","mData": "Encumbrance", "sWidth": "35%" },
                                                { "sTitle": "Release","mData": "Release", "sWidth": "45%" },  
                                                 { "sTitle": "Paid","mData": "Paid", "sWidth": "45%" },
                                                 { "sTitle": "Balance","mData": "Balance", "sWidth": "45%" },                                            

                        ],
                        "paging": false,
                        "ordering": false,
                        "data": Customers,
                        "info": false,
                        "bJQueryUI": true,
                        'sDom': 't',
                        "columnDefs": [{
                            "targets": [0],
                            "bSearchable": false,
                            "bSortable": false,
                            "className": 'details-control',
                            "mData": null,
                            "defaultContent": '',                               
                        }]
        });

    //On row click show child table
    $('#EncumbranceSummaryTable tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = ecumTbl.row(tr);

        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
            var innerPOTbl= S$("#innerPOTable").DataTable(
                   {
                       "bJQueryUI": true,
                       "aoColumns": [                               
                                               { "sTitle": "FY", "mData": "fiscalYrs", "sWidth": "20%" },
                                               { "sTitle": "Ln","mData": "ln", "sWidth": "15%" },
                                               { "sTitle": "F/F/A","mData": "ffa", "sWidth": "30%" }, 
                                               { "sTitle": "Project ID", "mData": "projectID", "sWidth": "25%" },
                                               { "sTitle": "Source Type","mData": "sourceType", "sWidth": "30%" },
                                               { "sTitle": "Encumbrance","mData": "encumbrance", "sWidth": "35%" }, 
                                               { "sTitle": "Released","mData": "released", "sWidth": "35%" }, 
                                               { "sTitle": "Paid","mData": "paid", "sWidth": "35%" },
                                               { "sTitle": "Balance","mData": "balance", "sWidth": "35%" },                                               

                       ],
                       "sDom": 'lfrtip',    
                       "data":PurchaseOrderList,
                       "paging": false,
                       "ordering": false,                         
                       "info": false,
                       "bJQueryUI": false,               
                   });      
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution using DataTables "[draw](https://datatables.net/reference/event/draw)" event.  I find this solution more comfortable as it is part of the Datatables object and placed in the "draw" event ensures it fires only after the table has been fully initialized and then on performed on each draw event.

```
var table = $('#sample')
  .DataTable({
    // your table configuration...
  })
  .on('draw.dt', function () {
    table.rows().every(function () {
      this.child(format(this.data())).show();
      this.nodes().to$().addClass('shown');
      // this next line removes the padding from the TD in the child row 
      // In my case this gives a more uniform appearance of the data
      this.child().find('td:first-of-type').addClass('child-container')
    });
});

// this is my format function for the child data
//  do as you need for your case
function format(d) {
  // `d` is the original data object for the row
  return  '<table class="row-detail">' +
          '<tr>' +
            '<td title="State">' + d.rState + '</td>' +
            '<td title="Comment">' + d.rComment + '</td>' +
            '<td title="Category">' + d.rCategory + '</td>' +
          '</tr>' +
          '</table>';
}
```

And here is the style class for the child TD and its table.

```
<style>
    .child-container{
        padding: 0 !important;
    }

    table.row-detail {
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 100%;
    }

    table.row-detail td {
        padding: 5px 10px !important;
        border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
    }

</style>
```

Comment: This is the quickest way I found. Thanks buddy !! you saved my day !!

Answer (score 0):

> **SOLUTION**

Add this code to show all child rows:

```
$("#EncumbranceSummaryTable").DataTable().rows().every( function () {
    this.child(format(this.data())).show();
    this.nodes().to$().addClass('shown');

    // Child table initialization
    var innerPOTbl = $(".child-table", this.nodes().to$()).DataTable(
       // ... skipped
    );
} );
```

See [`row().child()`](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row%28%29.child%28%29) for more information.

> **DEMO**

```js
/* Formatting function for row details - modify as you need */
function format ( d ) {
    // `d` is the original data object for the row
    return '<table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0" border="0" style="padding-left:50px;">'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Full name:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.name+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extension number:</td>'+
            '<td>'+d.extn+'</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
        '<tr>'+
            '<td>Extra info:</td>'+
            '<td>And any further details here (images etc)...</td>'+
        '</tr>'+
    '</table>';
}
 
$(document).ready(function() {
  
    var table_data_json = '[{"name":"Tiger Nixon","position":"System Architect","salary":"$320,800","start_date":"2011/04/25","office":"Edinburgh","extn":"5421"},{"name":"Garrett Winters","position":"Accountant","salary":"$170,750","start_date":"2011/07/25","office":"Tokyo","extn":"8422"},{"name":"Ashton Cox","position":"Junior Technical Author","salary":"$86,000","start_date":"2009/01/12","office":"San Francisco","extn":"1562"}]';
  
    var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "data": JSON.parse(table_data_json),
        "columns": [
            {
                "className":      'details-control',
                "orderable":      false,
                "data":           null,
                "defaultContent": ''
            },
            { "data": "name" },
            { "data": "position" },
            { "data": "office" },
            { "data": "salary" }
        ],
        "order": [[1, 'asc']]
    } );
     
    // Add event listener for opening and closing details
    $('#example tbody').on('click', 'td.details-control', function () {
        var tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        var row = table.row( tr );
 
        if ( row.child.isShown() ) {
            // This row is already open - close it
            row.child.hide();
            tr.removeClass('shown');
        }
        else {
            // Open this row
            row.child( format(row.data()) ).show();
            tr.addClass('shown');
        }
    } );

    // Show all child nodes
    $("#example").DataTable().rows().every( function () {
        this.child(format(this.data())).show();
        this.nodes().to$().addClass('shown');
    });  
 
} );
```

```css
td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_open.png') no-repeat center center;
    cursor: pointer;
}
tr.shown td.details-control {
    background: url('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DataTables/DataTables/1.10.7/examples/resources/details_close.png') no-repeat center center;
}
```

```html
<link href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

<table id="example" class="display">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</thead>

<tfoot>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Position</th>
        <th>Office</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for the code. but his code will only open the first row not all the rows,

Comment: @Rani, added example to demonstrate that the solution works.

Comment: @Rani, most likely it fails on your side because you try to initialize child table by using ID (`innerPOTableMost`). I have updated the code to reflect that. Also you access jQuery inconsistently, `S$` and `$`, so it's not clear whether it's a typo or mistake.

Comment: Thanks for your input, the reason behind adding S$ is because i am using Jquery.NoConflict. But the code behind which you gave to initialize the child table is not working for me  i am getting this error"0x800a138f - JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'aDataSort' of undefined or null reference"